# Implement polygon tool on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to imitate polygon tool in paint to allow user to draw same on my canvas.
Below is what i have coded so far but some how it is not exact same as paint tool.
Also i would like to know is there any way to fill this shape once it's drawn.
 Can anyone please help.

```
    var startPointX = "", startPointY = "", endpointX, endpointY, isnewShape = false;
function tool_polygon() {
var tool = this;
this.started = false;

this.mousedown = function (ev) {
    tool.started = true;
    tool.x0 = ev.offsetX;
    tool.y0 = ev.offsetY;


    console.log('mousedown');
    if (startPointX == "" && startPointY == "") {
        startPointX = tool.x0;
        startPointY = tool.y0;
    }
    console.log('startPointX ' + startPointX + ' startPointY ' + startPointY + ' ev.offsetX ' + ev.offsetX + ' ev.offsetY ' + ev.offsetY + ' isnewShape ' + isnewShape);
    //if ((Math.abs(startPointX - ev.offsetX) < 5) && (Math.abs(startPointY - ev.offsetY) < 5) && (startPointX != ev.offsetX && startPointY != ev.offsetY) && !isnewShape) {

    //keeping average gap of 5 pixels as the canvas is smaller and can't get exact start point
    if ((Math.abs(startPointX - ev.offsetX) < 5) && (Math.abs(startPointY - ev.offsetY) < 5) && isnewShape) {
        alert('point matched');

        isnewShape = false ;
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(endpointX, endpointY);
        //context.moveTo(ev.offsetX, ev.offsetY);
        context.lineTo(startPointX, startPointY);
        startPointX = "";
        startPointY = "";
        endpointX = "";
        endpointY = "";
        context.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
        img_update();
        tool.started = false;
    }
    else {
        if (startPointX == "" || startPointY == "" || endpointX == "" || endpointY == "")
            return;

        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(endpointX, endpointY);
        isnewShape = false;
        context.lineTo(ev.offsetX, ev.offsetY);
        endpointX = ev.offsetX;
        endpointY = ev.offsetY;
        context.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
        img_update();
    }


};

this.mousemove = function (ev) {
    if (!tool.started) {
        return;
    }
    console.log('mousemove');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(startPointX, startPointY);
    context.lineTo(ev.offsetX, ev.offsetY);
    endpointX = ev.offsetX;
    endpointY = ev.offsetY;
    context.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
};

this.mouseup = function (ev) {
    if (tool.started) {
        console.log('mouseup');
       isnewShape = true;
        tool.started = false;
        img_update();
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Canvas is basically just a bit-map image. Whatever you draw on the canvas is stored as pixels not as shapes. So once drawn you cannot go back and fill the shape. What you can do is create shapes as objects with properties, such as fill colour and the steps to redraw the shape. Then when you wish to change properties you do it within the object and re-draw the canvas.

I have constructed a project that among other things draws polygons that you can re-colour.

My project http://canvimation.github.com/ may help to do what you want.

Help files are at https://sites.google.com/site/canvimationhelp/

The source code for my project is at https://github.com/canvimation/canvimation.github.com

Please feel free to fork or copy code should you wish to do so.